# zfs-fuse file permissions problems on CentOS/RHEL 5

Tags: linux, permissions, zfs, fuse, zfs-fuse

I'm working with [zfs-fuse](http://zfs-fuse.net/) as a way to provide filesystem compression on existing CentOS 5 servers. I'm dealing with a highly-compressible dataset (80%), so zfs-fuse comes in handy. I'm encountering file permission problems with the storage pools.

It appears that zfs-fuse is ignoring or only partially recognizing file permissions for non-owners.

Assuming a zfs-fuse filesystem mounted at: `/app/november` comprised of files with permissions of 666 (-rw-rw-rw-) and owner "jack", I can *read* files and *delete* them as user "jill". However, I cannot write to those files or save them. Basically, everything is read-only if I'm not the owner of the files.

```
[jill@Vail /app/november]$ whoami
jill

[jill@Vail /app/november]$ ls -l testfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jack jack 27 Dec 18 12:12 testfile

[jill@Vail /app/november]$ touch testfile
touch: setting times of `testfile': Operation not permitted

[jill@Vail /app/november]$ rm testfile 
[jill@Vail /app/november]$ touch testfile
[jill@Vail /app/november]$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jill jill 0 Dec 18 13:57 testfile
```

Any ideas? Is there a fix for this? I think this is a Fuse issue, as I've seen [similar issues](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.fuse.zfs/7132) elsewhere for this and other Fuse filesystems...

The `zfs-fuse` package was downloaded from the EPEL repository. 

`rpm info`...

fuse-2.7.4-8.el5

zfs-fuse-0.6.9_p1-6.20100709git.el5.1

Edit - The mount output is as follows, showing zpool mounts and the Fuse info.

```
[root@Vail ~]# mount
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p9 on /app type xfs (rw,noatime,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k,nobarrier)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p8 on /tmp type ext3 (rw,noatime)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p7 on /var type ext3 (rw,noatime)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p3 on /usr type ext3 (rw,noatime)
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
kstat on /zfs-kstat type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other)
vol1 on /vol1 type fuse (rw,allow_other,default_permissions)
vol1/november on /app/november type fuse (rw,allow_other,default_permissions)
vol1/december on /app/december type fuse (rw,allow_other,default_permissions)
```

Comment: can you provide mount output?

Comment: Revised with mount information.

Comment: can you give us the permissions of /app/november after it's been mounted?  `ls -la /app/november`  thanks.

Comment: `ls -ld /app/november/` returns `drwxrwxrwx 2 jack jack 3 Dec 18 13:57 /app/november/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try upgrading to a more recent fuse version. Fuse 2.8 introduced a new function (FUSE_VFS_HAS_DEFAULT_PERM) which if IIRC has to do with group permissions

Don't know the specifics any more, but I think the group perms were to slow to implement properly before that time.

Comment: I tried updating fuse on the system. The userspace and tools updated, but the fuse.ko kernel module is part of the RHEL 5 kernel. It can't be updated easily. Do I need to patch the kernel source?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO rights for remove file are given by rights for directory (remove is operation on the directory), not the file...
And what will doing:

```
echo "1" > testfile
```

as a jill, when testfile is owned by jack?

Comment: `echo "1" > testfile 
-bash: testfile: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Hmmm... Then it seems to be a bug... :-(.